# Mysqli finding result (shouldn’t do) but doesn’t find result when entered directly in database consol. PHP7 XAMPP

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp

The mysqli $result echos out fine and works if entered directly into the database (using xampp. PHP Version 7.1.4).
However in the script it appears to always return a result! - kind of..
TEST1 is triggered but not TEST2?? and TEST3 is not triggered.
My testing right now should only trigger TEST3 – that indeed works entered directly!
So what’s broken?? 
-Thanks

```
for ($x=0; $x<count($TransArray); $x++) // for each entry in the array
{
    $enterID = (string)$TransArray[$x][0];
    $enterC  = (string)$TransArray[$x][1];
    $enterQ  = (string)$TransArray[$x][2];

// Check to see if the CQID is in the fler_datatable with a matching language 
// If so then we need to 'update'
// if not then we need to 'insert'
// NOTE : ‘cqid’ and ‘language’ make a unique value in the table

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT rowID FROM fler_datatable 
    WHERE cqid='$enterID' AND itemid='SYS_DATA_TRANS' AND language='$LANG' LIMIT 1"); 
        if ($result) // found it!
        {
            echo"<BR>TEST1";
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
                echo"<BR>TEST2";
                $SetRow = $row['rowID'];
                echo"<BR>Updatting translation entry on row ".$SetRow.".";
                mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE fler_datatable SET class='$enterC', question='$enterQ' WHERE rowID='$SetRow'");
            }
        }
        else // Not found 
        {
        echo"<BR>TEST3";
        echo"<BR>Adding new translation entry .";
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO fler_datatable (cqid, class, question, itemid, language, date)      
        VALUES ('$enterID', '$enterC', '$enterQ' , 'SYS_DATA_TRANS', '$LANG', '$date')");
        }
}
```

Comment: Read a manual please, as you don't understand what does `mysqli_query` return.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's because your are using non-OOP mysqli to execute query and getting result (which is true) but while accessing it you are using OOP-based mysqli.

So use one approach throughout, ie. fetch row as `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)`.

Comment: Seems to have the same effect.

Comment: Did you check doing the print_r($row)?

Comment: Where ever I put it print_r($row); prints nothing.

Answer (score 0):

A friend had the answer =3

```
if ($result) {}
else {}
```

Is the wrong way to test for 'no result'.
if ($result) is true even if it finds no rows.

**The correct code to use is...**

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0 ) {} // found
else {} // Nothing found
```